# Doctrine QueryBulider Syntax Error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to do a simple query on one table based on multiple values passed in from request, and am missing something that would be obvious to a more experienced person.

This does not work:

```
public function showAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'GET') {
        $id = $request->get('locationid');
        $kfType = $request->get('type');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getManager();

        $data = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->select('d')
                    ->from('DashDataBundle:Data',  'd')
                    ->where('d.locationid = :locationid' AND 'd.kfType = :kfType' )
                    ->setParameters(array('locationid'=> $id,'kfType'=> $kfType))
                    ->setMaxResults(100)
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
    }
```

Error is:
Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, boolean given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/path/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr/Base.php line 89

But, this does work on just one parameter:

```
public function showAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'GET') {
        $id = $request->get('locationid');
        $kfType = $request->get('type');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getManager();

        $data = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->select('d')
                    ->from('DashDataBundle:Data',  'd')
                    ->where('d.locationid = :locationid')
                    ->setParameter('locationid', $id)
                    ->setMaxResults(100)
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
    }
```

What am I failing to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're combining two strings with AND, which is why it's complaining about getting a boolean.  Remove the extra quotes so that AND is part of a single string parameter within the where function.

Comment: it must be `->where('d.locationid = :locationid AND d.kfType = :kfType' )`